# Anapanasati and Metta

Tags: meditation, meditation-breath, anapanasati, metta, meditation-metta

#### Background

Hi all, i have been practicing Metta and self-compassion meditation for a while but have just switched (back) to following the first couple of exercises in the Anapanasati Sutta (translations: [Thich Nhat Hanh](https://plumvillage.org/sutra/discourse-on-the-full-awareness-of-breathing/), [Thanissaro Bhikkhu](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html))

I can successfully practice exercises 1-4, but when i come to 5 and 6 i have a hard time to feel joy and happiness (i have a low-grade depression and also anxiety and maybe this is interfering with my practice)

#### Question

**Can we (is it recommended to) integrate Metta practices in the 5th and 6th exercises of the Anapanasati Sutta?**

(And how can this be integrated? We may not want to switch the phrases since these are already provided in the Sutta, but thoughts can still be filled with Metta and help us that way)

I'd like to find a way to successfully practice these two exercises so i can continue in my spiritual development and practice of the Sutta

Please provide references if you have!

---

Grateful for help!

Kind Regards, Tord

Answer (score 1):

We cannot integrate Metta practices in the 5th and 6th stages of the Anapanasati Sutta because the 5th and 6th stages of the Anapanasati Sutta arise naturally from the calming of the breathing at the 4th stage. Metta practises can be done separately.